# GCP Logs-Based Monitoring: Trigger an alert when no logs are received

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-monitoring

I have an application that I'm setting up logs-based monitoring for.  The application will log whenever it completes a certain task.  I want to ensure that the application completes this at least once every 6 hours.

I have tried to replicate this rule by configuring monitoring to fire an alert when the metric stays below 1 for the given amount of time.

Unfortunately, when the logs-based metric doesn't receive any logs, it appears to act that there is "no data" instead of a value of 0.

Is it possible to treat segments when no logs are received as a 0 so that the alert will fire?

Screenshot of my metric graph:
[image]

Screenshot of alert definition:
[image]
You can see that we receive a log for one time frame, but right afterwards the line disappears and an alert isn't triggered.

Comment: Why not create a 2 logs alert metric instead, so there will always be a data received, then create [labels](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/labels) for each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`absent_for`](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference#absent_for-tabop) and MQL based Alert.

> The `absent_for` table operation generates a table with two value columns, active and signal. The active column is `true` when there is data missing from the table input and `false` otherwise. This is useful for creating a condition query to be used to alert on the absence of inputs.

Example:

```
 fetch  gce_instance :: compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/usage_time
  | absent_for 8h
```

Comment: fetch path has be your own logging metric, of course. But as it is censured on the screenshot, i put gce cpu usage_time as an example.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you!  I didn't realize that MQL was capable of more than what is exposed on the UI.